# Python Import Path Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

So, [this article](https://realpython.com/python-import/#basic-python-import) did a very good job explaining paths & imports and the most portable way to handle python projects. I have read it twice but I do not know what I am doing wrong. I decided for this project that, I will not manipulate `PYTHONPATH` nor use `sys` to do path hacks (So, please those suggestions are not ideal). I would appreciate suggestions on the recommended way to fix this which should be portable (run locally, in docker, and anywhere) as well.

Here is my project structure

```
sample/
    src/
        __init__.py
        package1/
            __init__.py
            module1.py
            module2.py
            
    tests/
        unit/
            __init__.py
            test_module1.py
            test_module2.py
    setup.cfg
    setup.py
```

In `src.package1.module2` I have

```
def demo()
    return "foo"
```

In `src.package1.module1.py` I am just importing one method from module1 so I have:

```
from module2 import demo

def main():
    print("foo")

def helper1():
    return "help"

def helper2()
    return "bar"
  
if __name__ = "__main__":
    main()
```

In `tests.unit.test_module1.py`

```
from src.package1 import module1

@unit.mock.patch("module1.helper1")
def test1():
   pass

def test2():
   pass
```

I have a `setup.cfg` like this

```
[metadata]
name = my_test
version = 1.0.0
description = sample project

[options]
packages = src
```

And `setup.py` with this:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup()
```

After installing the package locally with `python3 -m pip install -e .` and executing the main method in `module1` like this:
`python -m src/package1/module1`,  everything works fine

However, when I run the unit test like this
`python -m unittest discover -s tests/unit -p "test_*.py"`

I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named module1`. This is coming from the `src.package1.module1` file.

NB: I intend to run this app docker and locally for development.

My question is

1. What is the best way to organize a python project having this component and what is the standard way of managing paths for import?
2. What am I doing wrong? Honestly, I think the article explained everything but I am surprised that I still could not figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue: So two things were wrong (updated/corrected the question).

1. It happens that I need in the import statement of `src.package.module1.py`, I needed to use full qualified path starting from the `src` package. So instead of `from module1 import demo` it should `from src. package.module1 import demo`. Funny that I had it correct while asking the question but had it wrong in the code.
2. Also in the test file, `@unit.mock.patch("module1.helper1")` should be `@unit.mock.patch("src.package1.module1.helper1")` - it should have the fully qualified path.

That said, I am still curious to know the standard way people organize their python project.